# What is the plugin that allows you to have a circular GUI for selection?

Tags: scripting

As seen here https://youtu.be/joq0xWyZoU4?t=1m3s

He works really fast so I couldn't clip a screenshot, but its the circular pattern of buttons that pop up around your cursor. What is the name of the plugin or setting that this makes this happen?

Comment: Got a feeling you mean "pie menus"

Comment: Thats it, thank you. How do I credit you with the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin I was thinking of is Pie Menus, thanks to [@batFinger](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger) for the answer.